# Azure Data Factory - Integration Runtime for Linux box

Tags: azure, runtime, integration, azure-data-factory

I wanted to copy data files from Linux machine to Azure Blob Storage. I am using Azure Data Factory for this(as per the requirement). Can somebody plz help me how to install/ from where to get the Integration Runtime to install on that Linux machine.

Thanks

Comment: were you able to get it working? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Azure Data Factory Integration Runtime (self hosted) is currently only available on windows (see system requirements at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39717).

You could use a Linux file share, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-file-system for more details.

Comment: Is it possible to use SMB share on linux without Integration Runtime (self hosted) installed on Windows? I can't find a way to configure it this way. Azure Integration Runtime fails with error `Access \\host\shared\ is not allowed on Azure integrate runtime.` when trying to connect to `\\host\shared\`